# Pagination to Retrieves a list of fulfillment orders on a shop for a specific app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, fulfillment

https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/assigned_fulfillment_orders.json?assignment_status=fulfillment_requested

We are using above shopify admin API to retrieve fulfillment_orders that are requested but we have a case that we only want to fetch the orders that has requested recently not the older one, the API does not contain any parameter to filter records based on updated_at, we can use parameter 'since_id' but in our case fulfillment_order request is not sequential therefore parameter 'since_id' not working

Even if API does not contain parameters to filter records other than status, e.g. updated_at time then do we have any pagination link in this API how can we fetch more than 250 fulfillment orders.

We have tested the API does not contain any pagination Link any other way to fetch only new requested fulfillment order using parameters or pagination ??

Answer (score 0):

When you download assigned fulfillment orders, the expectation is that you have acted on the list you receive. So once you download even one, you are likely going to act on it, and thus change it. So now the status of that assigned fulfillment order has changed, and you won't be seeing as assigned again, since you have dealt with it.

So I am not sure why you think they just sit around in some list and get read and re-read and stale. If you download them, you act on them, and they are no longer sitting around to be re-read over and over again.

Comment: Yes, but in our case we are sending fulfillment orders to third party warehouse where they can took time to either accept/reject fulfillment orders
e.g. they took 5 hour to accept/reject
and we receive 1000 fulfillment orders request in this time period

Comment: You'll figure it out. The problem is not in reading the available work from Shopify. It is in how you've architected your fulfillments.

Comment: We are using fulfilment order notification callback, one we receive fulfilment request we fetch assign fulfilment orders but the accept/rejected fulfilment request is based on other service, so every time we receive request then get assigned fulfilment orders fetch all the previous orders as well because we only have status filter in this API, if we have some updated-at filter then it will work as expected. Please suggest what we are doing wrong here.
     https://shopify.dev/apps/fulfillment/fulfillment-service-apps#receiving-fulfillment_request-and-cancellation_request-notifications